# Any opensource library to capture log messages and show them like chrome inspector's console panel?

Tags: javascript

I m searching for some library, which can capture all the log messages and then can show like chrome inspector's console panel?

I can override console.log or make it accessible via proxy to capture log messages, but rendering them in readonly way looks like a lot more work. It would be gr8 If someone can guide/help me here.

I want to show it in Browser.

Comment: Log messages from where ?  Your software, the browser, the OS ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I *think* what is requested is a window that displays all output from JavaScript's `console.log(message)`, without having to use the browser's inspector feature.

Comment: Want to show console messages of a webpage in browser without opening console.